# Facebook test user permissions

Tags: facebook, permissions, facebook-test-users

I've been trying for days now to get my test users to get different permissions.

Even though my app specifies permissions, the test users don't get them.
Several ideas from old pages don't seem to work any longer. I've tried:

*Updating the app permissions, login the test user out and back in, no request for new permissions takes place...

*Not authorizing the app at creating of the user. (instead login the testuser, authorize the app. the test user still don't get the right permissions (or even asked for them even though the facebook tutorial says it should)

*I've tried to manually create test users:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?
installed=true&name=NAME
&locale=en_US
&permissions=read_stream,publish_actions *this is the extra permissions*
&method=post
&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

This doesn't work either, facebook give error message back...

Does anyone have an insight into this that is new/relevant?

Note: After 2 weeks of working with facebook integration, it's soooo frustrating to see that their own help pages are out of date/invalid/broken... You constantly get links that after trying them you realize they obsolete...

Anyone? :-)

Comment: _“Even though my app specifies permissions”_ – and _how_ does it do that …?

Comment: CBroe - In the app settings.

I've let this go for a few weeks, however, I now suspect (through reading but not working on the problem) that I might have to make a specific call in code to ask for more permissions, is that true?

If so, then why does Facebook have a tool for setting the permissions you want? (under app setting/permissions)

Comment: As said a thousand times before already: The permissions you set there are for access through the app center only. When you handle login yourself, you have to ask for permissions via the `scope` parameter …